# Is there any difference between a brahmin feed trough and a bathtub?

Tags: fallout-4

The brahmin feed trough *looks* the same as a bathtub, but they seem to be distinct items as far as the game is concerned.

I am thinking of doing an experiment at Sanctuary where I store my brahmin feed trough in the workshop and give them a bathtub from one of the empty houses.

Has anyone already tried this?

Can a bathtub be substituted for a feed trough?

(The same question has been asked at [gamefaqs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/xboxone/164593-fallout-4/answers/413990-brahmin-feed-troughs-or-bathtubs) but not answered, and I found a [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/fo4/comments/3sh6ss/howwhere_to_get_a_brahmin_for_settlement_livestock/) that mentions a bathtub, but it's not clear if the poster actually built a bathtub or is just being inaccurate and is referring to the feed trough).

Comment: I would assume that because they are different objects that the functionality is tied to the object.

Comment: I'd be surprised to see a trough being substituted for a bathtub, but I guess you'll find out soon enough. Remember to answer your own question when you do.

Comment: I have never personally seen brahmin gathered around a bathtub.

Comment: If they were going to gather around the bathtub, wouldn't they have tried to do that even before you moved it?

Comment: @Jason_c_o, I don't know, all the bath tubs were in houses, so maybe brahmin just can't get inside a house. The fact I didn't see them in the bathroom of a house doesn't prove they wouldn't go to a bathtub if it was accessible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The feed trough while looking the same gets coding that causes the brahmin to go to it the normal bathtub lacks this. So they will go back to wondering around the settlement if you try and remove the trough and replace it with a normal bathtub.

Comment: I couldn't remove it while they're eating at it anyway, but I still want to try to confirm what you said.

Comment: Can confirm. Brahmin congregate around the troughs but not bathtubs.